# Events consumption in Kafka like AMQ Advisory Topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am unable to find the concept in Kafka which is similar to the Advisory Topics in AMQ.

I want to consume all the event on a topic so that my system could take action on the basis of those events like

- When a participant joins the topic, an event should be published
- When a participant leaves the topic, an event should be published

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Spring for Apache Kafka. I believe such a functionality has to be implemented on Apache Kafka broker first of all...

Comment: @ArtemBilan Alright. Please suggest the way of it's implementation at broker side

Answer (score 1):

> consumers, producers and connections starting and stopping.

You'd need to build this yourself (trigger events in your clients, or use the Interceptor interface to do the same). Otherwise, add network packet analysis around your brokers and clients

> temporary destinations being created and destroyed... brokers sending messages to destinations with no consumers

Unclear what these mean. Brokers do not send. Consumer poll.

Temporary consumers fallback to the previous point.

> messages expiring on topics

The log cleaner logs contain this information. You should be able to use log processing tools to parse the relevant data out of this to see both compaction and deletion events, but Kafka will not create producer records for these on its own

Comment: I got the point. Using the confluent interceptors for my required case.
 https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.3/control-center/docs/installation/clients.html#confluent-monitoring-interceptors

Comment: Those are just for monitoring via Control Center, though, not doing the things you've asked for